# MVC Entity Framework Ignore Class/Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently building an MVC site using Entity Framework. I have created following class:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace .Models {

    public class VehicleTableData
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public Dictionary<string,string> StandardVehicleData { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Dictionary<string,string> AdditionalData { get; set; }
    } }
```

However, I would like it to be ignored by Entity Framework as when I try to create a view with it I get the error that there is no valid key.

[image]

Comment: Are you defining `public DbSet<VehicleTableData> VehicleTableDatas { get; set; }` in your `DbContext`?

Comment: yes :( thank you! it was a late night!

Comment: Ha yeah we all have them. I will add as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the class defined in your `DbContext` with the following line of code:

```
public DbSet<VehicleTableData> VehicleTableDatas { get; set; }
```

This will cause Entity Framework to include the class. Once the above line is removed it will not be included.

You could also remove the `[NotMapped]` attributes as this would only apply to properties that you would not want saved to the database in a model included in your `DbContext`.